# I get error SettingWithCopyWarning trying to concate two columns of a data frame in one new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

I am trying to concatenate two columns of a `dataframe` in a new one and add it to the same data frame, but I keep getting  this error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead.
```

I am trying this:

```
Df["concat"] = Df["Technologies"] + ";" + Df["Other Actions"]
```